# Probability that $\beta_A$ > $\beta_B$ using the posterior distributions directly

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, stan

Suppose a regression coefficient was estimated in sample A (from country A) through a Bayesian linear regression model. The resulting posterior distribution, comprising 10,000 simulations, was obtained and stored.

Weeks later, the same model was subsequently applied to an independent sample (country B), referred to as sample B, resulting in another posterior distribution containing 10,000 simulations.

Is it valid to estimate the probability, Pr($\beta_A$ > $\beta_B$), by directly sampling the posterior distributions obtained from Bayesian linear regression models fitted separately on sample A and sample B, or is it necessary to fit a new model in which the coefficients are estimated in a unified manner?

Comment: It depends on what you might mean by "unified manner."  To the extent that the presence of data from one country might affect the posterior distribution of the coefficient for another country, *it's a different model.*  You have to decide which version of your model is the one appropriate for your assumptions and objectives.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I assume the countries and coefficients are independent.

Comment: Yes, but the prospect of combining the data in your modeling suggests you might be thinking of estimating a common parameter, such as the variance of the response, or coefficients of covariates, or whatever.  That is separate from (conditional) independence of the responses.

Comment: If there is no connection between the two models, the probability can be directly estimated by Monte Carlo from the two respective samples.